# Using the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X,Y$ compact metric spaces, $X\times Y$ the product space and $\mathcal A$ the algebra generated by the functions $f:X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$ of the form

$$f(x,y) = g(x)h(y), \qquad g\in C(X), \; h\in C(Y).$$

Then  what I want to prove is that $\mathcal A$ is dense in $C(X\times Y)$, So I want to use the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

Given that $\mathcal A$ is a algebra we only need to check that $\mathcal A$ separates points and that the constant functions are in $\mathcal A$.

So to see the latter we only pick $f(x,y)=c$ for some constant $c$, and we can always write $c=c·1$ then we define $g(x)=c$ and $h(y)=1$, then the constants are in $\mathcal A$.

Now to see that $\mathcal A$ separates points, given $(x,y)\not=(x_0,y_0)$ we may define in general

$$f(x,y)=xy-xy_0-x_0y-x_0y_0=(x-x_0)(y-y_0)$$

Then $g(x)=x-x_0$ and $h(y)=y-y_0$ and we know that these are lines which are injective so we are done.

The thing is that I am not sure of my above proof so Can someone help me to improve it and fix the mistakes please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What do $xy$ and $x-x_0$ mean?

Comment: They are variables multipliying, this is a vector in $X \times Y$ in converted to a number and then I multiply  :)

Comment: You can't do that; there's no operation on a metric space, in general.

Comment: jajaja right :) I was thinking of that right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right with the constants, but there is a flaw in the second part. When you write: "*[G]iven $(x,y) \ne (x_0, y_0)$ ...*", you use $(x,y)$ as a *fixed, given* point. Then - in the next line -, you write: $f(x,y) = ...$, now $(x,y)$ is any point of $X \times Y$. And: What is $x-x_0$? $x$ is a point in $X$, a compact metric space, how do you substract these?

But: You are on the right track, both things can be fixed. Let's start with the points. To have $x,y$ for the general point, let's denote the two given ones, by $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$, say. Then $x_0 \ne x_1$ or $y_0 \ne y_1$. If $x_0 \ne x_1$, let $g \colon X \to \mathbf R$ be any continuous function with $g(x_0) \ne g(x_1)$, for example (to model your difference), $g(x):= d_X(x,x_0)$ (the distance from $x$ to $x_0$). And $h(y) := 1$. Then $f(x,y) := g(x)h(y)$ does the trick. If $x_0 = x_1$, then $y_0 \ne y_1$ and we are done with $g := 1$, $h(y) := d_Y(y,y_0)$.

Comment: Ok :) jajajaj that is what I didn't know how to implemented, but let me check your answer, If I have a question can I ask you?